# What if you can't find the question that yours is supposedly a duplicate of?

Tags: feature-request, bug

Occasionally, as a fairly new user, I see interesting questions that are flagged as duplicate, but I search and I find no questions that really adequately answer the issue.

I really think that if you want to flag a question as as duplicate, the onus is on you to link to the question(s) that are duplicated. And, considering the rules of duplication means the answers to the first question are sufficient for the second, those answers should address each of the points of the new question, not some of them.

Sometimes it just feels that good questions are being shut up by those who seem to be IN and that can be very dampening to the enthusiasm of new users.

So what am I to do, considering my small reputation??

I'm tagging this as a bug since I think the duplicated question MUST be included in the flag.

Comment: Are you asking about the "already answered here" type questions?

Answer (score 10):

If a question is flagged as a duplicate, then one of two things should have happened:

1. There should be a comment to that effect in the comments of the question

OR

2. There should be a link to the duplicate in the body of the question.

The first is true if the question is *in process* of being closed. The second is true if the question is closed.

If neither is true, please flag the question for moderator attention.